# How to get SendPort's Pipeline properties via Biztalk Explorer Object Model C#?

Tags: c#, biztalk, pipeline

**Scenario is:**
Let us have a shared pipeline in shared application and many send/receive ports are using that in different applications. I want to remove all references of specific Pipeline from all applications.
**I also want to store properties of pipeline on each port which will be used for some other reason**.
For now I am stuck in "**How to access properties of pipeline on each port**"
If anybody have idea please share to help

Thanks
Reference for your help is given below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee268648(v=bts.10).aspx

Comment: Have you looked at BizTalk Documenter?  https://biztalk2010autodc.codeplex.com/

Comment: In particular look at https://biztalk2010autodc.codeplex.com/workitem/8 where I document the default configurations in a pipeline (still working on accessing the actual configured ones).

Answer (score 0):

As of BizTalk Server 2006, all Pipeline configuration is stored per-instance.  Just click the little button next to the Pipeline in the Port Configuration dialog.

However, these statements are incongruent:

- I want to remove all references of specific Pipeline from all applications.
- I also want to store properties of pipeline on each port which will be used for some other reason.

Can you explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish?